# Checking To See If A Object Has An Associated File Attribute In A Django Template

Tags: django, templates, if-statement

I have a model which allows users to upload an .ics file to a calender field via the FileField.

However this is not required so some objects will have associated files, other will not. In my template I want to output different things depending on this. I thought this would work...

My view passes a all the model objects in a seminarData variable..

```
{% for seminars in seminarData %}
    {% if seminars.calender %}

        {{seminars.title}}
        {{seminars.message}}
        <a href="{{seminars.calendar.url}}"> Download .ICS File</a>

    {% else %}
        {{seminars.title}}
        {{seminars.message}}

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't seem to work... Everything just goes straight to the else section even those objects with associated files in the calender field.

Could it becasue in my model I have

```
calendar = models.FileField(upload_to="/uploadedCal/", blank=True)
```

And I need to have null=True or something?

I played around inequality operators aswell with no luck... Thanks

Edit: I think the solution would be pretty straightforward I just can't see it annoyingly!

Comment: Calendar is spelt incorrectly in your if statement ;-)

Comment: Why don't you try it with null=True for yourself, then you can come back and say that doesn't work (or that it does).

Comment: wow that was a stupid mistake. Appololgies and thank you

Comment: would you like to post that as a reply so I can make it as the answer Tony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calendar is spelt incorrectly in your if statement ;-)